# C program repeated malloc / calloc followed by free error: "free(): invalid next size (fast)"

Tags: c, memory-management, mathematical-optimization, free

I recently found an [open source software](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/~more/dgsol/) writen in C written around 20 years ago, and I've been trying to modify it slightly to suit my needs.

In particular, I've been trying to run the program in a loop such that it will process multiple instances of the problem it solves at once (rather than having to call it multiple times, say with a shell script).

Now, I have to declare that I'm very new to C (in fact picked up C in order to work with this code), though I do have some experiences programming in higher level languages like Java, Python and Haskell.

The bulk of the computation is done in the subroutines, which was written in Fortran - whilst the C part is used for file reading / writing. I am looking to make it such that it will read in a file containing multiple instances of the problem, and output multiple solutions corresponding to the input instances. Sounds simple enough.

Here's the loop I came up with, (stripped down to where I think the bugs lie)

```
while (fgets(smiles, STR_MAX_LENGTH, input) != NULL) {
    /*
    Allocate memory.
    */
    iInd = calloc(numDs, sizeof(int));
    jInd = calloc(numDs, sizeof(int));

    lbd = calloc(numDs, sizeof(double));
    ubd = calloc(numDs, sizeof(double));

    n = 3 * numAtoms;
    lintWkSp = 2 * numAtoms > numDs ? 2 * numAtoms : numDs;

    ldblWkSp = 22 * n + 21;

    fOpt = calloc(1, sizeof(double));
    dErr = calloc(3, sizeof(double));
    xOpt = calloc(n, sizeof(double));

    intWkSp = calloc(lintWkSp, sizeof(int));
    dblWkSp = calloc(ldblWkSp, sizeof(double));

    /*
    Call the DG optimizer to obtain a set of solutions.
    */

    seed = 1;
    for (k = 0; k < numSols; k++) {
        /*
        Call the DG optimizer.
        */

        dginitial(&numAtoms, xOpt, &numDs, iInd, jInd, lbd, ubd, &seed, intWkSp);
        dgopt(&numAtoms, xOpt, fOpt, &numDs, iInd, jInd, lbd, ubd, intWkSp, dblWkSp);
        dgerr(&numAtoms, xOpt, fOpt, &numDs, iInd, jInd, lbd, ubd, dErr);
    }

    /*
    Clean up.
    */

    free(iInd);
    free(jInd);

    free(lbd);
    free(ubd);

    free(fOpt);
    free(xOpt);
    free(dErr);

    free(intWkSp);
    free(dblWkSp);
}
```

The point of the program is to read a file in, which contains distances between some points in space, and try to find a 3D embedding of it. I've modified it such that it will read in distances for an instance of the problem, separated by a separator (I've used `###` as a separator), and call the Fortran subroutines `dgopt` on that instance and output the solutions into another file, repeating until the whole file is consumed.

Now for the problem: it seems that the problems aren't being solved correctly when I put them in a loop like this. Some solutions seem to be wrong and give unrealistic errors: however they work correctly when I put them through the original version of the program (also works correctly when I single them out and run my version but only on that instance) - indicating I've broken something when trying to do multiple instances in a loop. Ultimately I think with the loop, I am not giving each instance the same starting conditions for each run as they would've in the original version.

I thought this may have been due to the optimizer working on arrays that have already been worked on by a previous instance, so I tried to make sure this won't happen by using `calloc` instead of `malloc`, which will initialize them all to `0`. This did not seem to have fixed things as now the program will not run altogether - giving me `free(): invalid next size (fast)` as in the title.

The error with `free` appears to happen with the `intWkSp` and `dblWkSp` arrays, and the error occurs when the instances in the input has varying sizes (`numDs`), where `intWkSp` often fail when the previous problem instance was larger than the current one - it works correctly (`dgopt` optimizer gives correct answers also) vast majority of the times when all of the instances in the input has the same size.

Perhaps the two problems (`dgopt` optimizer giving wrong answer, and followed by the one with `free`) are related?

I understand I may have made many mistakes here since I do not know much C - please if you have any comments about my code stylistically I would also like to hear them :)

Here's the [full version](https://pastebin.com/t2AQnDkS) of the code, which replaces the file `./dgsol_s/dgsol.c` (I think it'd be too long and probably not too useful to paste in here, but just in case the errors were not in the parts I isolated out)

Comment: you destruct your heap, may be with multiple free or free with an invalid address (not the result of a malloc/calloc/realloc) or writing at an invalid address etc . If you have *valgrind* available on your OS install it if not yet done and run your program with it, it will check your memory accesses / free / etc

Comment: Can we assume `numAtoms;` in `n = 3 * numAtoms;` is properly initialized elsewhere before this call?

Comment: Also, is there an additional header, source or library you haven't included on pastebin? With the file posted, the compiler has no clue what `dginitial_`, `dgopt_` or `dgerr_` are?